# Why does nginx does not test all available locations?

Tags: nginx

I have the following nginx server configuration:

```
server {
    error_log   /var/logs/error_stage.log debug;
    root        /var/htdocs_stage/;
    index       index.php index.html;

    # A
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # B
    location ~* \.(txt|xml|js)$ {
        expires 8d;
    }

    # C    
    location /. {
        deny all;
    }

    # D
    location = /wp-config.php {
        deny all;
    }

    # E
    location ~* ^\/wp-content\/.*\.(txt|md|log)$ {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Then I make a request to following URL:

```
https://example.com/wp-contents/themes/demo/readme.txt
```

I expect that this request is handled by location **rule E** and access is denied. But nginx actually **applies rule B** and serves the file with a 8-day expiration cache!?

In the error_stage.log file I find following details:

```
... [debug]: *1396 http uri: "/wp-contents/themes/demo/readme.txt"
...
... [debug]: *1396 generic phase: 0
... [debug]: *1396 rewrite phase: 1
... [debug]: *1396 test location: "/"
... [debug]: *1396 test location: "wp-config.php"
... [debug]: *1396 test location: ~ "\.(txt|xml|js)$"
... [debug]: *1396 using configuration "\.(txt|xml|js)$"
```

Here I notice, that nginx only tests the rules A, B and D. Out of these three, B is the correct one.
However, as you see in my nginx config, there are two more rules that are not even tested...

--> What is the error in my configuration?

Btw: The error_stage.log file is only used by this specific server block. So I am absolutely sure, that no other server block is used to process the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "error" in your configuration is order of regex (`~`) locations.

NGINX checks regex locations in order of occurrence in configuration files. As soon as it finds one that matches, it will immediately satisfy request using that location. It's just the way it works.

So if you simply move the location E upper than location B in configuration, then E will be the one to apply.